# database query according to file input empty or not in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

So i am changing my project from core PHP to Codeigniter. I have a edit for in which their are 3 input type file. Now i want to run my query according to these inout file. like if input file 1 is empty than don't update value else update. I did it in core PHP like this:

The name of input type file are: image1, image2, image3

### mysqli query in core PHP:

```
if(!empty($photo1))
{
    $p1=str_replace("-","",time().$photo1);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $folder.$p1);

    $query .=",`image1`='$p1'";

}
if(!empty($photo2))
{
    $p2=str_replace("-","",time().$photo2);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'], $folder.$p2);

    $query .=",`image2`='$p2'";
}
if(!empty($photo3))
{
    $p3=str_replace("-","",time().$photo3);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'], $folder.$p3);

    $query .=",`image3`='$p3'";
}
```

Now how to do this in codeigniter model:

### controller

```
public function store_ad()
{
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $d_email=$this->session->userdata('dealer_email');
    $p_type=$this->input->post('property_type');
    $p_subtype=$this->input->post('property_subtype');
    $p_for=$this->input->post('p_for');
    $p_name=$this->input->post('p_name');
    $p_price=$this->input->post('p_price');
    $state=$this->input->post('state');
    $city=$this->input->post('city');
    $loc=$this->input->post('location');
    $pincode=$this->input->post('pincode');
    $about=$this->input->post('p_about');
    $stat=$this->input->post('status');

    $config['upload_path'] = './images/properties';
    $config['allowed_types']='gif|png|jpeg|jpg';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('image1'))
    {
        $data1=$this->upload->data();
        $img1=$data1['raw_name'].$data1['file_ext'];
    }
    if($this->upload->do_upload('image2'))
    {
        $data2=$this->upload->data();
        $img2=$data2['raw_name'].$data2['file_ext'];
    }
    if($this->upload->do_upload('image3'))
    {
        $data3=$this->upload->data();
        $img3=$data3['raw_name'].$data3['file_ext'];
    }
}
```

How to crearte model according to the non empty input file. I am storing the name of the file in database

Answer (score 0):

Inside your method in the model class check if the files you want to upload is empty or not e.g

```
public function update($data_array, $img1, $img2, $img3){
  if(!empty($img1)){
    $data_array['img_column1'] = $img1;
  }
  if(!empty($img2)){
    $data_array['img_column2'] = $img2;
  }
  if(!empty($img3)){
    $data_array['img_column3'] = $img3;
  }

  return $this->db->insert('YOUR_TABLE_NAME', $data_array);

}
```

Hope this helps....